# Watin with Nant example

Tags: nant, watin

Can you give me a simple example of nant build file which builds watin/nunit tests from .csproj file with all needed dependencies?

Comment: There are a few examples in the NAnt distribution. See the ones with NUnit. Also - what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my nant build file which I finally designed for my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="WatInTests" default="test">
  <include buildfile="common.properties" />
  <include buildfile="properties_watin.properties" />
  <property name="run.dir" value="${jenkins.jobs.dir}\<my_project>\workspace" />     
  <property name="currentFileset" value="${projectFileset}"/>
  <property name="precondition.test" value="${currentFileset}.Tests.PreconditionTest"/>
  <property name="results.folder" value="${results.dir}\${now.datetime}"/>  

  <target name="clean">  
   <delete verbose="true">
     <fileset basedir="${project.build.dir}">
       <include name="**\*" />
     </fileset>
   </delete>
<copy file="App.config" 
        tofile="${uitests.dir}\${currentFileset}\App.config" inputencoding="utf-8" 
        outputencoding="utf-8" overwrite="true">
            <filterchain>
                <expandproperties />
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
  </target>
  <target name="build" depends="clean">
                <echo message="Start building ${currentFileset}"/>
                <copy file="${nunit.reference}" todir="${uitests.dir}\${currentFileset}\bin\debug" failonerror="true"/>                
                <copy file="${nunit_core.reference}" todir="${uitests.dir}\${currentFileset}\bin\debug" failonerror="true"/>
                <exec program="${project.utils.msbuild.exe}" workingdir="${uitests.dir}\${currentFileset}">
                          <arg value="${ProjectSlnPath}"></arg>                                 
                          <arg value="/p:Configuration=${BuildMode}"></arg>
                </exec>
                <echo message="Build succeeded"/>
                <echo message="Copy build to ${run.dir}"/>
                <copy todir="${run.dir}" overwrite="true">
                  <fileset basedir="${watintests.dir}\${currentFileset}\bin\debug">
                       <exclude name="*.svn" />
                  </fileset>
                </copy>
   </target>

  <target name="precondition" depends="build">
     <mkdir dir="${results.folder}" />
     <exec program="${nunit.file}" failonerror="true" verbose="true" workingdir="${run.dir}">
                <arg value="/run:${precondition.test}" />
                <arg value="${run.dir}\${nunit.config.file}" />
     </exec>     
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="precondition">
     <exec program="${nunit.file}" verbose="true" workingdir="${run.dir}"> 
                <arg value="/exclude:Precondition" />               
                <arg value="${run.dir}\${nunit.config.file}" />
     </exec>
     <copy file="${run.dir}\TestResult.xml" todir="${results.folder}" failonerror="true"/>
</target>
</project>
```